# how to find the equation of an ellipse rotated by 25°?

Tags: functions

I know how to shift an [ellipse] along the x-axis: $\frac {x^2}{8.75^2}+\frac{y^2}{5^2}=1 $

modifying the value of $x$

$$\frac {(x-8.75)^2}{8.75^2}+\frac{y^2}{5^2}=1 $$

Can you tell me how to find the equation of that ellipse when it is rotated by a certain angle, for example 25°?

[image]

Comment: See [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $x$ by $x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta$ and $y$ by $y \cos \theta + x \sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle to be rotated (in this case $\theta = 25^\circ$)