# What is equation of moved and rotated ellipse, parabola and hyperbola in XY plane?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Canonical equations of ellipse, parabola and hyperbola are well-known.

But I have hard times trying to find those three equations for an ellipse, parabola and hyperbola in any place of $(2D)$ coordinate plane and rotated by a given angle.

Could anyone please help to summarize those three equations with parameters, so that those parameters allow to draw moved and rotated ellipse, parabola and hyperbola in $XY$ plane?

Comment: This might be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477762/how-to-find-the-equation-of-an-ellipse-rotated-by-25

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. Are you asking what the equation is if you take a known ellipse (say), described by its major and minor axes, but in standard position, and rotate it through a given angle? Or are you asking how to tell, from the equation, what the lengths of the axes are, and through what angle the ellipse has been rotated?